# how to implement a search by object by value if each of them is invested in years and months

Tags: javascript, json, object, multidimensional-array

I made a website and I just can't manage to search by multidimensional array / object (I don’t know what the difference is).

Before adding the year and month, I accessed them directly by identifier array[id][field]

how to implement search by nested structures in a multidimensional array

I tried to pre-define the year and month with additional fields in the interface.
and it looks creepy and incomprehensible.

```
{
  "2018": {
    "Aug": {
      "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "appeal_date": "2018-08-24",
        "city_of_residence": "aaa",
        "patient_name": "John",
        "patient_age": 62,
        "coordinator": "aaa",
        "source": "aaa",
        "birth_date": "1956-06-30",
        "contact_person_name": "",
        "contact_person_role": "",
        "contact_person_phones": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "diagnosis": "aasasd",
        "status": "9",
        "departure_date": "2016-02-18",
        "arrival_date": "2020-01-23",
        "patient_phones": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "editable": true
      }
    }
  },
  "2019": {
    "Oct": {
      "65": {
        "id": 65,
        "appeal_date": "2019-10-18",
        "city_of_residence": "asfsac",
        "patient_name": "asvsas",
        "patient_age": 62,
        "coordinator": "",
        "source": "asfasfa",
        "birth_date": "1956-06-30",
        "contact_person_name": "",
        "contact_person_role": "",
        "contact_person_phones": "",
        "diagnosis": "assdbcx",
        "status": "1",
        "departure_date": "",
        "arrival_date": "",
        "patient_phones": "",
        "editable": true
      }
    },
    "Jun": {
      "64": {
        "id": 64,
        "appeal_date": "2019-06-04",
        "city_of_residence": "afsfsa",
        "patient_name": "asvac",
        "patient_age": 62,
        "coordinator": "",
        "source": "agwdawdawd",
        "birth_date": "1956-06-30",
        "contact_person_name": "",
        "contact_person_role": "",
        "contact_person_phones": "",
        "diagnosis": "agsags",
        "status": "1",
        "departure_date": "",
        "arrival_date": "",
        "patient_phones": "",
        "editable": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

all i need is to update some fields in the right object

```
patients [2019] ['Oct'] [65] ['diagnosis'] = 'aaaaa'
```

something like this, but in a certain month the patient may not be right

I would like something like this:

```
patients.nestingSearchByKey (65) ['diagnosis'] = 'aaaaa'
```

their identifiers are unique and not repeated

I apologize for my English

any ideas please

Comment: What do you mean by 'but in a certain month the patient may not be right'? That there may not be a patient with that ID for the given month?

Comment: I had in view of the inside of a certain month there may not be the identifier we are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` to get an array of keys in the object.

```js
var pts = {
  "2018": {
    "Aug": {
      "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "appeal_date": "2018-08-24",
        "city_of_residence": "aaa",
        "patient_name": "John",
        "patient_age": 62,
        "coordinator": "aaa",
        "source": "aaa",
        "birth_date": "1956-06-30",
        "contact_person_name": "",
        "contact_person_role": "",
        "contact_person_phones": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "diagnosis": "aasasd",
        "status": "9",
        "departure_date": "2016-02-18",
        "arrival_date": "2020-01-23",
        "patient_phones": [
          "",
          ""
        ],
        "editable": true
      }
    }
  },
  "2019": {
    "Oct": {
      "65": {
        "id": 65,
        "appeal_date": "2019-10-18",
        "city_of_residence": "asfsac",
        "patient_name": "asvsas",
        "patient_age": 62,
        "coordinator": "",
        "source": "asfasfa",
        "birth_date": "1956-06-30",
        "contact_person_name": "",
        "contact_person_role": "",
        "contact_person_phones": "",
        "diagnosis": "assdbcx",
        "status": "1",
        "departure_date": "",
        "arrival_date": "",
        "patient_phones": "",
        "editable": true
      }
    },
    "Jun": {
      "64": {
        "id": 64,
        "appeal_date": "2019-06-04",
        "city_of_residence": "afsfsa",
        "patient_name": "asvac",
        "patient_age": 62,
        "coordinator": "",
        "source": "agwdawdawd",
        "birth_date": "1956-06-30",
        "contact_person_name": "",
        "contact_person_role": "",
        "contact_person_phones": "",
        "diagnosis": "agsags",
        "status": "1",
        "departure_date": "",
        "arrival_date": "",
        "patient_phones": "",
        "editable": true
      }
    }
  }
}

function search(patients, id) {
  var patient;
  const years = Object.keys(patients);
  years.forEach(year => {
    const months = Object.keys(patients[year]);
    months.forEach(month => {
      if (patients[year][month][id]) {
        patient = patients[year][month][id];
      }
    });
  });
  
  return patient;
}

const p = search(pts, 64);
if (p) {
  p['status'] = 0;
  console.log(pts);
} else {
  console.log('Not find patient with id 64');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You can clarify why it turns out to change the value in pts from the variable p, they are also different variables. to me it looks like magic

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you currectly and you're keeping the current object structure, you just need to check for patient existence:

```
var patient = patients[2019]['Oct'][65];

if (patient) {
    patient['diagnosis'] = 'aaaaa';
}
```

Comment: Yes, I keep the structure of objects.

but not only check patient availability but update some values in this patient